# If $G$ solvable and $f$ a surjective homomorphism between $G,G'$, then $G'$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a solvable group, $f: G \rightarrow G'$ a surjective homomorphism. I need to show that $G'$ is solvable.

Let $G$ be solvable. Then there exists a sequence of subgroups $$\{e\}=H_r\triangleleft H_{r-1}\triangleleft\cdots \triangleleft H_{1}\triangleleft H_0=G$$
such that $H_{i+1}\triangleleft H_i$ for all $i=0,1,...,r-1, $ and such that $H_i/H_{i+1} $ is abelian.

We know that $f(H_i)\triangleleft f(G)$, but since $f$ is surjective, $f(H_i)\triangleleft G', \forall i=0,1,...,r-1.$ Also, $f(H_i)\subset f(H_{i-1}),\, $thus $f(H_i)\triangleleft f(H_{i-1}), \forall i=0,1,...,r-1.$ Thus we get $$\{e\}=f(H_r) \triangleleft f(H_{r-1})\triangleleft  \cdots \triangleleft f(H_1)\triangleleft f(H_0=G)=G'.$$ It remains to be shown that $f(H_i)/f(H_{i+1})$ is abelian.

Here I can not go further. I need a solution proposal or some hint. Thanks.

Comment: You could show $f(H_i)/f(H_{i+1})$ is abelian through commutator subgroups: https://pastebin.com/raw/BxpGPm4M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $i$ you can define $\varphi:H_i/H_{i+1}\to f(H_i)/f(H_{i+1})$ by $\varphi(hH_{i+1})=f(h)f(H_{i+1})$. I'll leave it to you to check that $\varphi$ is well defined, a homomorphism and onto. Hence $H_i/H_{i+1}$ being abelian implies that $f(H_i)/f(H_{i+1})$ is abelian.